# Converting a 3D array into GDF format

Tags: image, matlab

I stacked 10 images using the `cat` function, getting an image stack labeled myImage, which has dimension: `100x100x10` (each image has `100x100` dimension). I want to convert this file into a GDF file using `write_gdf`. However, when I try to run this conversion,

```
myImage = cat(3,X{1:NumberOfFiles});
s = write_gdf('stack.gdf',myImage);
```

I expected `s` to be a 3D matrix with dimension `100x100x10` with values equal to that of `myImage`. Instead,I simply get s to be a 1D variable: `s=3`.

In the `write_gdf` help, it is mentioned:

```
NAME:
        write_gdf
   PURPOSE:
        write data files in gdf format.
   CATEGORY:
        General Purpose Utility
   CALLING SEQUENCE:
        fid = write_gdf(filename,data)
   INPUTS:
        file:   Complete pathname of the file to be written.
   OUTPUTS:
        data:   Data structure.  For example, if the original
            data was stored as an array of bytes, then
            DATA will be returned as an array of bytes also.
   RESTRICTIONS:
        Current implementation does not support structures or
        arrays of structures.
   PROCEDURE:
        Reasonably straightforward.
        Determines if the file is ASCII or binary, reads the size
        and dimension info from the header, and reads in the data
```

Please help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Schorsch, I was expecting `s` to be a 3 dimensional file with dimension `100x100x10` as well. The file `s` is being written, but it is a 1D variable with value 3. Ill edit the question to make it clearer what I am expecting. Thank you

Comment: Yes sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the help section to be misleading. If you examine [the code](http://gibbs.engr.ccny.cuny.edu/Matlab/work/write_gdf.m), you will find the following:

```
function [fid]=write_gdf(fn, data)

fid=fopen(fn,'w');
```

*Note*: I have removed all unrelated parts of the code.
You provide a file name (`fn`) and the data (`data`) to the function. Internally, it calls `fopen` on the file name an stores the file ID in `fid`. From the [`fopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) documentation:

> fileID: the File identifier of an open file, specified as an integer.

This is the only output of this function to Matlab. And this is what you see as `s=3`.

---

Why the help paragraph says:

```
%  OUTPUTS:
%       data:  Data structure.  For example, if the original
%              data was stored as an array of bytes, then
%              DATA will be returned as an array of bytes also.
```

I can only  guess. Maybe it is meant that `data` is the output **to** the file (but not to Matlab). This might just explain **how** the data is "output" to the file.